# G.P. and Infinite Series Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many terms of the geometric series 7, 7/2, 7/4, 7/8, ... must be taken in order that the sum may differ from the sum to infinity by less than 0.01? (Ans: 11 terms)

Some help, please?

Comment: @jspecter: I don't even know how to start doing it when I saw this question.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $x=1/2$ in the formula
$$
1 + x +x^2 + \cdots + x^n = \frac{{1 - x^{n + 1} }}{{1 - x}}.
$$

EDIT:

Let $S_n$ be the $n$th partial sum, so that
$$
S_1 = 7,
$$
$$
S_2 = 7 + 7/2 = 7(1+1/2),
$$
$$
S_3 = 7 + 7/2 + 7/4 = 7(1+1/2+1/4),
$$
from which you can conclude that
$$
S_n = 7 (1+1/2+\cdots+1/2^{n-1}).
$$
Further, let $S$ denote the sum to infinity, so that
$$
S = 7 (1+1/2+1/4+\cdots) = 7 \cdot 2 = 14.
$$
You are asked to find the least $n$ such that
$$
S - S_n < 0.01.
$$
Noting that
$$
S_n = 7 (1+1/2+\cdots+1/2^{n-1}) = 7 \frac{{1 - (1/2)^n }}{{1 - 1/2}} = 14(1 - 1/2^n ),
$$
it remains to find the least $n$ such that
$$
14 - 14(1 - 1/2^n ) < 0.01,
$$
or
$$
14/2^n < 0.01,
$$
or
$$
2^n > 1400.
$$
Since $2^{10} = 1024 < 1400$ and $2^{11} = 2048 > 1400$, the answer is $11$.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't ask for the *least* $n$, just some $n$ that works.  In this case we can find the least $n$ as seen, but in many cases it is more convenient to work with estimates, rather than exact formulas for the partial sums, and then we can still find an $n$ that works.

Comment: @GEdgar: "the least $n$" (rather than "some $n$") corresponds to "must be taken" (rather than "can be taken").

Comment: And anyway, the OP mentioned that the answer is "$11$ terms".

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to sum a geometric series?  Basically you are being asked how late to start so that the sum from there on is less than 0.01.  So if you write the sum starting from $n$ to $\infty$ you should be able to find $n$ that meets this.  A geometric series stays geometric if you cut off some of the first terms.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We know how to sum geometric series ($\dfrac{a_0}{1-r}$ where $a_0$ is the first term and $r$ is the ratio). We also know how to sum partial geometric series, by either directly adding them up (applicable here) or by recalling [some useful formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series).

You could subtract these, or you could realize that the difference is just another geometric series with a different starting point.